# Getting "Segmentation fault" after installing nodejs 4/5/6 on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: node.js, npm, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I've tried to replace the default installed version of node (v 0.10.29) on Raspbian Jessie with node 6 by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs nodejs-legacy
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The removal and installation of the new node version is successful but when I run

```
node -v
```

or

```
npm -v
```

I get "Segmentation fault". Does anyone know what the issue might be and how it could be resolved?

I've also tried version 4 and 5 of node but the end result is the same.

Comment: Are you sure that that will install an ARM-based version of Node? What does `file -L $(which node)` return?

Comment: It returns: /usr/bin/node: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=844a4851be257d83af8d9be3fbc35beee5d8e5e4, stripped

Comment: I've also tried to install the ARM binaries found at https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.0.0/node-v6.0.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz, but to no avail. The result is the same.

Comment: I have tried the latter on my RPi2 and it works just fine (although I'm running LibreELEC, not Raspbian).

Comment: same here with raspbian, any progress on that @Simon? I have tried a dozen of different approaches and always had this error :(

Comment: Don't know if it is 100% related but I am facing a similar problem : https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8015

Comment: I finally got it to work by using the Node version 6.5.0 ARMv6 binaries found here https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.5.0/node-v6.5.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz.